# SharedPreferences not working on real device FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I used SharedPreferences to make remember username and password to log in next time without asking a password. It was working well when I debug using my real device with USB cable. But it's not working in my device when I build APK and install it. I don't know what I'm missing.

I save data in login page like this`

```
Future<Null> loginUser(isLogin, name, fac, year, gender) async {
final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString('Name', name);
prefs.setString('IsLogin', isLogin);
prefs.setString('Faculty', fac);
prefs.setString('Year', year);
prefs.setString('Gender', gender);
prefs.setString('Email', email);

print(prefs.getString('Faculty'));
```

}

I used this code in main page....

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return NewMain();
  }
}

class NewMain extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _NewMainState createState() => _NewMainState();
}

class _NewMainState extends State<NewMain> {
  var name, fac, year, gender, email;
  var goToLogin = true;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    checkRem();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (goToLogin)
      return MaterialApp(
        home: Login(),
      );
    else
      return MaterialApp(
        home: MainClass(name, fac, year, gender, email),
      );
  }

  void checkRem() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (prefs.getString('IsLogin') == 'Yes') {
      goToLogin = false;
      fac = prefs.getString('Faculty');
      name = prefs.getString('Name');
      gender = prefs.getString('Gender');
      year = prefs.getString('Year');
      email = prefs.getString('Email');
    }
  }
}
```

It will move to MainClass if goToLogin is false. 
It's working perfectly in debug. It's not working on the built apk app.

**Solved**

It was problem with my IDE. Updated and fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is u calling `checkRem()` which is async in `initState()` so build method getting called before complete execution of `checkRem()`.

Soln:
 wrap it with `futureBuilder()` or calling `setState()` after complete execution of method