# SharedPreferences working on android emulator but not on real device

Tags: android, flutter, sharedpreferences

As said in the title, I have some bools and Strings stored in SharedPreferences. It work like a charm with the emulator and when i install my app on my real device, the bool and Strings are just not sotred. I'm using api 29 on the emulator and 30 on my device, can it be this? (I just checked and when debugging on my real phone it worked!! But still not when i'm installing the app with the apk file from the build task...)
Any ideas? I don't think my code will be very relevant here but if needeed I can add it!
Thanks for your help!
Also, the app is much heavier when debugging (almost 5 times) and much less smooth, any ideas why? maybe because of the SharedPrefs?

Edit of the code:

```
Switch(
    value: appsLoad.instagram ?? false,
    onChanged: (value) {
       setState(() {
       appsLoad.instagram = value;
       sharedPref.save("user", appsLoad);
       });
     },
),
```

This is how i save the value, the sharePref.save refers to

```
save(String key, value) async {
final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
prefs.setString(key, json.encode(value) ?? false);
}
```

i used a lot of [this](https://medium.com/better-programming/flutter-how-to-save-objects-in-sharedpreferences-b7880d0ee2e4) website for the sharedPreferences.

Comment: [Check is this helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60808893/7704650)

Comment: thanks: but i'm not using the initState, just with the regular setState

Comment: Definitely the some code would help. Regarding the performance, it's expected, in debug mode the app is a lot slower.

Comment: @danypata i edited, is it enough?

Comment: How about removing the `final` keyword?

Comment: @MartinZeitler no it doesn't change anything but thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

If you read the setState comment section

> Generally it is recommended that the `setState` method only be
> used to wrap the actual changes to the state, not any computation
> that might be associated with the change. For example, here a
> value used by the [build] function is incremented, and then the
> change is written to disk, but only the increment is wrapped in
> the `setState`:

```
Future<void> _incrementCounter() async {
  setState(() {
    _counter++;
  });
  Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final String dirName = directory.path;
  await File('$dir/counter.txt').writeAsString('$_counter');
}
```

Following the example you shouldn't call the future inside `setState`

```
Switch(
    value: appsLoad.instagram ?? false,
    onChanged: (value) async {
       setState(() {
         appsLoad.instagram = value;
       });
       await sharedPref.save("user", appsLoad);
     },
),
```

Take note an emulator doesn't run as fast as a device (with the profile/debug mode its slower than a real one) so that's why in an emulator you cannot perceive this kind of error

Comment: Nothing changed, the values aren't save :/ but appreciated the help!

Comment: Where do you read the saved key preference?